# slick slider vertival row

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

Добрый день, маленькая проблема со слайдером slick. Мне нужно сделать вертикальный слайдер с 2 столбцами и тремя строками. Сделал использую код ниже все работает. Но проблема в том что слик получается прокручивает по 6 элементов. То-есть. Одни в одном `<div class="slick-slide>` 6 слайдов. Можно ли как то сделать чтобы слик построчно делал прокрутку?

```
    $('#portfolio-slider').slick({ 
    rows: 3, 
    slidesPerRow: 2,
    vertical:true,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    speed:1000
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

`slidesToShow: 3`

Возможно, это вам поможет